# How to cearte a contract with sub contracts

Tags: contract-development

I want to use Ethereum in donate part of my website

**I need unique payment address for each user**

As I search I find out that I need a contract that each time called, generate a new contract and so I can use this new address

And I want to all payment goes to the master wallet And I can access all value without any limited

And I really worry about my privacy and Donater privacy

Is it possible? or there is another way?

Plz leave a comment guide and right down the code

Best regard

Answer (score 3):

What you're saying is possible, but I'd advice against it. Just purely because it might be expensive to create a new contract every time someone wants to donate.

If the system really is only for donations, I fail to see why you need to identify each user. Why not just present users an Ethereum address where they can send donations?

If you have some reasons to make the transactions traceable in some way, I'd suggest writing a contract which has one `payable` function with a unique parameter for each user. So some function like this:

```
function donate(uint256 payerIdentifier) public payable {
    // ...
}
```

Then your off-chain system has to issue each user an identifier and they can donate by using that identifier.

Of course that sort of system can be cheated (using a different identifier) but the level of security depends on your needs.